# Spectral radius of $\text{diag}(s)+s1'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds, spectral-radius

I'm interested in getting spectral radius $\rho$ of the following $d\times d$ matrix

$$A=\text{diag}(s)+s1'$$

Where diag indicates diagonal matrix, and $1$ is a vector of 1's. For example, for $d=3$, it is the following

$$A=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 s_1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & s_2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & s_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
+
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 s_1 & s_1 & s_1 \\
 s_2 & s_2 & s_2 \\
 s_3 & s_3 & s_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The following seems to be a way to bound on $\rho$ using $\infty$-norm of $s$ and its dual norm, but it gets loose for large $d$, is there a better estimate?

$$\rho\le \|s\|_\infty + \|s\|_1$$

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see a nice analytical form for large $d$, but for small $d$, a sequence of tighter bounds bounds may be obtained by using the fact that

$$\rho^n \le \|A^n\|_*$$

for any norm $\|\cdot\|_*$

For instance, for $n=2$ and L1 matrix norm (max-column-norm), this gives

$$\rho^2 \le \|s\|_\infty^2+\|s\odot s\|_1+\|s\|_\infty \|s\|_1+\|s\|_1^2$$